# How to swap between 2 root view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a game with two rootViewControllers - one for the Menu and the other for the Game itself.

When the user switches between the Game and the Menu, I want to switch the rootViewController. Ultimately my questions is, what is the best way to do this? Or is there another approach for switching stacks that makes more sense than having 2 rootViewControllers?

As it stands, I have an instance of a navigationController in my appDelegate. When I want to switch rootViewController, I initialise a new navigationController, set it's rootVC, then set this to the instance of the navController in the appDelegate. The code to transition from the menu to the game looks like this:

```
//Initialise the new Root Controller
GameViewController *rootController = [[GameViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *newNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
[rootController release];   
newNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:newNavController animated:YES];

//Setting the appDelegate's navController to the new navController allows the menu to dealloc. 
//This must happen AFTER the newNavController has been loaded. 
MiniAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MiniAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
appDelegate.navController = newNavController;
[newNavController release];
```

Is this bad practice?? I have an issue with my app when it resumes from background and I think this might be what's causing it.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you are NOT using Cocos2d framework for building your games? It is extremely easy in Cocos2d to switch between different scenes and layers.

Comment: I didn't look at Cocos2d when I initially built the app and now it's a bit late to retrofit it... But I'll probably use it for the next app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be going well by not presenting a modal view controller, but to use a `UIViewController` that manages the underlying view controllers.

Similar to this:

```
// MainNavigationController extends UINavigationController

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIViewController childViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    self.childViewController = [MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName...];
    [self pushViewController:childView...];
}

-(void)launchGame {
    self.childViewController = [GameViewController alloc] ... ];
    self.viewControllers = [NSArray array];
    [self pushViewController:childView...];
}
```

This way you hold a reference to your current view controller all the time and manage the displaying of them in one place.

You should also pass both child view controllers a reference to the `MainNavigationController` so that you can use delegate methods.

**edit:**

To clarify things a bit regarding the first comment: Yes, the `MainNavigationController` is the starting point of your app which handles the displaying of the menu and the game itself.

The line `self.viewControllers = [NSArray array]` is used to just empty out the list of current view controllers when launching a game. This is done to replace the menu with the game instead of just pushing it. This way, you don't have 8 view controllers when the user goes to the menu, to the game, to the menu and so on.

A similar method would be used to open the menu while playing the game: A button would ask the MainViewController to open the menu. You can either to it the same way the `launchGame` method works or you can *then* present it the modal way to keep the game state or you put a smaller in-game menu before that or whatsoever - many ways to handle things from there on.

Comment: So do I create an instance of this MainNavigationController in my appDelegate? And I reference this instance whenever I want to switch between navControllers? And do you mean self.viewControllers = [[NSArray array] arrayWithObject: self.childViewController]; I don't quite follow the code...

Comment: Edited my post to elaborate on this one

Comment: Right - I think I'm getting it. Haven't used class extensions before (as opposed to categories). Having read up about them, I understand that it's a way to declare required methods in the header or implementation file of any class... And then define these methods in the implementation of that same class. So I create an '@interface UINavigationController ()' line plus your method declarations but I can put it anywhere? In which case, which class do I put it in? If I create a new 'Objective-C class extension' in X-code, it only creates a header file, no implementation. Bit confused.. But thanks!

Comment: You just create a new class that is based on (i.e. extends) `UINavigationController`. No need for class extensions here. You can however create a new protocol that your `MainNavigationController` implements, so that both menu and game know what methods are available to control the UI (like "Show Menu" or "Show Game" or "Show In-game Menu" or whatsoever)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

first add the `GameViewController` as a field to the Menu Controller

then use this to display it (in the menu controller class)

```
if(myGameViewController == nil) {
     myGameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc]
     initWithNibName: @"GameView" bundle: nil];
}
[self presentModalViewController: self.myGameViewController animated:YES];
```

and then use to remove it (in the GameViewController class)

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

What is does is open the game view as a child of the menu view This requires at least the GameViewController to be a UIViewController rather than a RootViewController.

Comment: The problem then is that if I push a subsequent viewController in the Game view using something like [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES]; nothing happens because presumably it's pushing the new VC on to the Menu stack which isn't visible...

Comment: you can use `[self presentModalViewController: self.myGameViewController animated:YES];` to push a new view on top a `UIViewController` So you can have the menu view push the game controller and the game view push subsequent views and it should work. I have an application that does exactly this with various UIViewControllers.

Comment: But then you lose the navigation bar and have to manually configure it for every VC that you present to get the behaviour that you'd otherwise inherit automatically when you push?

Comment: That's true I put a navigation bar on to every view I had manually. If you want to use Navigation Views I don't know what the corresponding method is.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use your Main Menu controller as the rootView controller and use it to push every other view modally (or just using the new `[self presentViewController:...]` in iOS5) ?

Even if you have multiple menu views you can always reach the main menu through the `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`'s rootView controller?? or even `[self presentingViewController]`