# Transitional Style when using setViewControllers:animated: on UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm setting a new stack of ViewControllers to my navigationController by doing the following:

```
 MainMenuViewController *mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
NSArray *controllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainMenuViewController];
[mainMenuViewController release];
[self.navController setViewControllers:controllerArray animated:YES];
```

The only problem is I can't seem to set the transitional style. Ideally I'd like it to flip. Is this possible? It's important that I use setViewControllers:animated rather than presentModalViewController since I switch back and forth between stacks and want to maintain the navigation control behaviours for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of swapping out entire navigation stacks, why not just maintain two navigation controllers and animate a transition between them? Seems cleaner to me.

UPDATE

I guess I could be of better assistance if I knew what you were trying to achieve, but I know that you can present a second nav controller modally from a first, and you can push a bunch of views onto it before/after presentation, etc. Also, out-and-out replacement of an existing stack of view controllers, especially if it's deep, may confuse the user, not to mention the Apple review team.

Maintaining two nav controllers in memory is not necessarily a big deal, as long as you *have* the memory (you probably do), and as long as the user is actually getting benefit.

Perhaps you can shed some light on your high-level purpose and we can go from there.

MORE

If you want it to flip, then you can set `navController2.modalTranstitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`, which will cause `navController2` to flip in when it is presented modally.

SO had some weird glitch about the time we were commenting below, it might have lost your updates.

Comment: Well I was doing something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570225/how-to-swap-between-2-root-view-controllers which didn't seem to be encouraged. Although there I had one navigation controller for which I reinitialised to a new rootViewController each time. Is it good practice to have 2 navControllers then? Don't you end up with both of them in memory at the same time?

Comment: You could do that - I don't think having an empty or 'short' nav controller on hand will be that big a deal. You could also try creating the second nav controller on demand, right before you present it. This might result in a little UI lag, or not. You'll have to test to see what works well.

Comment: This was my initial approach, and lag-wise it was fine. However I started getting crashes when resuming the app from background. The crashes only occur when I've switched between menu and game and then closed the app. Otherwise it resumes fine. So I was thinking that my handling of navigation controllers is probably to blame...

Comment: My last 2 comments seem to have vanished, but you can see my original problem in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570225/how-to-swap-between-2-root-view-controllers

Comment: It probably is... read "Modifying the Navigation Stack" in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW1